# How to convert timestamp to DateTime in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, ecto

How to convert the time in milliseconds to `Ecto.DateTime`?

The time in milliseconds is the number of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do this while preserving the millisecond accuracy:

```
defmodule A do
  def timestamp_to_datetime(timestamp) do
    epoch = :calendar.datetime_to_gregorian_seconds({{1970, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}})
    datetime = :calendar.gregorian_seconds_to_datetime(epoch + div(timestamp, 1000))
    usec = rem(timestamp, 1000) * 1000
    %{Ecto.DateTime.from_erl(datetime) | usec: usec}
  end
end
```

Demo:

```
IO.inspect A.timestamp_to_datetime(1466329342388)
```

Output:

```
#Ecto.DateTime<2016-06-19 09:42:22.388000>
```

Answer (score 19):

To convert timestamps to DateTime

```
DateTime.from_unix(1466298513463, :millisecond)
```

For more Details
https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/main/DateTime.html#from_unix/3

Answer (score 15):

Now it's very simple to do:

```
timestamp |> DateTime.from_unix!(:millisecond) |> Ecto.DateTime.cast!
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it can be done the following way, but some milliseconds will be lost.

```
timestamp = 1466298513463

base = :calendar.datetime_to_gregorian_seconds({{1970,1,1},{0,0,0}})
seconds = base + div(timestamp, 1000)
erlang_datetime = :calendar.gregorian_seconds_to_datetime(seconds)

datetime = Ecto.DateTime.cast! erlang_datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.from_unix have unit as second argument.
So passing in: :millisecond or :microsecond regarding to value you want to convert.